# Non-frequent 502 Bad Gateway errors

Tags: php, html, apache, nginx

I'm running a php script which starts with a start id and limit, and calls himself each time with the next id with `META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh"` until it reaches the limit.
The reason for the refresh is to keep track, to avoid timeout issues and just to divide the big task to smaller ones. Sometimes I get `502 Bad Gateway` errors. I have now idea why. I've never seen the server return such an error on any of the other scripts.
What can be the reason or/and how can I debug the reason?

Comment: I sometimes get such error on random sites, even giants like youtube or facebook, so it could be something related to ISP's gate and not to your server.

Comment: you must have a proxy somewhere between the browser and the server, and this is a message sent by the proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Before analyzing this, make sure your browser has a clear cache.

If you still get the errors, there are two common possible problems that could be occuring:

#### 1. Your firewall is functioning incorrectly.

This could be an issue if you are using a proxy, so your computer is not receiving back the protocol information that should be getting. Check your proxy/DNS settings.

#### 2. Your ISP is having an equipment failure.

Obviously, not much you can do about this. If the problem persists, and doesn't seem to be caused by you, you might want to contact your ISP.

(Also, check out this [helpful site explaining 502 Bad Gateway errors](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html)).